# Best actively maintained Java XMPP Library?

Tags: java, xmpp

I've seen several XMPP libraries for Java that seem to have little update activity in the past few years.

What is the best current XMPP library with support for:
 - Basic chat
 - TLS
 - MUC
 - PubSub

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps that is because XMPP has been stable over that timespan. Anyway, I like [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/), but I've done nothing more than experiment with XMPP.

Comment: Smack is good, and is used in a number of high volume, large commercial apps.  And I totally agree with the comment that lack of update activity doesn't mean the library isn't supported or solid.

Comment: That is true... but it makes it difficult to discern which are not progressing due to stability, vs which no longer receive any bug fixes or support for new extensions.

Comment: And as another datapoint here, there are several significant features that are SVN only at the moment (because of their lack of official releases).

Comment: Official releases are a bit of a problem right now due to administrative issues dealing with the code ownership.  Smack and other related projects are no longer actively maintained by ignite, but by the community instead.  There are still issues being resolved with regards to builds and releases which will hopefully lead to new releases actually occuring sometime soon.  But let me make it clear, the code is not stagnating, and updates are being made (as @jsight pointed out), there are just some issues with builds that need to be worked out.