# Can I develop IP-messenger(messaging/chat between LAN connected computer users) 

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing

i want to develop ip-messenger in Java RMI (messaging/chat between LAN connected computer users).

or should i use any other technology(tool).

the Java is only option for me?

found out about JMS and other technologies too, but which will be better

Comment: What do you mean "IP messenger"?  What is the application actually going to be used for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Read it. Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how much you want to do yourself.  Is this for educational purposes, or for a real application?

If the latter, I would use XMPP (Jabber).  This the latest open IM standard, used by such products as Google and Facebook chat (among others).  You can use one of the Java XMPP libraries (e.g. [Smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641224/best-actively-maintained-java-xmpp-library)).  Note that XMPP is a client-server protocol.

If you want to do it yourself, I would still not use RMI.  That will mostly lock implementations into using Java.  It also isn't really designed as a general networking protocol.  Rather, it's basically a long arm for one machine to manipulate objects on another machine.

Rather, start from the perspective of a clean network protocol that anyone can implement.  This can be either peer-to-peer or client-server. Then, make a Java implementation.

Comment: no it is not for real application.it is just for educational purpose.recently i found about JMS(java message service) is it an option?if i develop,then java is the only option because it is my project in java.

Comment: @navnit, JMS is really intended for software-to-software communications, not person-to-person.  You could probably find a way to use it, but I don't think it's ideal.